# Adding 2 integer values from database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am pretty new in C# and I'm making a program where the user can add a Network provider and reload. I already did the Add, Edit, Delete Network but I don't know on how to to the Reload Part where I need to get the current value of the load from the DB and add (addition) it to the new amount.

Example: Current balance = 12 and Reload = 35 --> Current Balance = 47

By the way, I am using MS Access.

Comment: Look at the UPDATE statement

Comment: You need to provide some code to show what you have done so far. I don't understand; you don't know how to add two numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Feel like I'm taking risk to answer your question but anyway..

Since we have no idea what is your desing and code looks like but I suggest to use [`UPDATE` statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx).

Here it's syntax;

```
UPDATE table_alias
SET expression 
WHERE <search_condition>
```

For your case, it can be like;

```
UPDATE YourTableName
SET Current_balance = Current_balance + 35
WHERE <search_condition>
```

This query adds `35` to your `Current_balance` column where you specified *search condition* in your table.

Of course, we could be more helpful if we see your desing and code..

> The user inputs the amount in the textbox. I'm doing it on Windows
>   Forms Application.

Let's try to write an example like this;

```
string s = TextBox1.Text;
int i;
if(Int32.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out i))
{
   using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
   {
      using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
      {
         cmd.CommandText = "Update TableName SET Current_balance = Current_balance + @p";
         cmd.Connection = con;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", i);
         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }
}
else
{
   //TextBox string is not a valid integer.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir. Actually I have a column Current_balance and new_amount. I need the user to input the new_amount and add that amount to the current balance. But since you already game me an idea, I'll just find a way to convert the input from string :).

Comment: @GailyGuzon How did you read user's input? In a web form, in a console stream..?

Comment: The user inputs the amount in the textbox. I'm doing it on Windows Forms Application. But I realized I think I don't need a column for the new_amount anymore, I just need to convert the input to an integer and add it to the current amount that's stored in the DB.

Comment: @GailyGuzon I try to made a small example in my answer. Take a look.